# How to create custom orderBy conditions in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects, with each object containing a Date and a WeekNumber, like so:

```
datesArray: [
          { Date: "2015-08-01T00:00:00", WeekNumber: 31 },
          { Date: "2015-09-01T00:00:00", WeekNumber: 36 },
          { Date: "2015-10-01T00:00:00", WeekNumber: 40 },
          { Date: "2015-11-01T00:00:00", WeekNumber: 44 },
          { Date: "2015-12-01T00:00:00", WeekNumber: 49 }
       ];
```

I also have access to a variable on scope which shows the **current week** (it is from backend).

```
$scope.currentWeek
```

I want to sort the object in the array by the following condition:

1. First date object in the array should be the week which is **next** (after current week), if there is any.
2. Next date object in array should be the week which is the **same as the current week**, if available.
3. Next should be a list of 5 date objects with **previous** week numbers, e.g. where weekNumber is less than current week.

It could probably be done with a custom filter function on the repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="date in datesArray | customOrderingFunction"></div>
```

Although I did not have much luck with the function, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: Can u show how would you like to have sorted your example ?

Comment: I think what you want to do is make a custom filter as you are already thinking. [Here](http://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/) is a great article which helped me build my own filter. Basically you want to run through your data 3 times and check for the conditions and push it to a temporary array which you return. Just like "Filter 2: Filters for repeats" in the link.

Comment: Does the ordering need to be changed based on user input or is it always the same? If it's always the same, I would sort the data immediately after fetching it using lodash's sort function https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy

Comment: Many thanks @CarstenFarving for the article, it helped me create my custom function. Basically I made 3 loops, and with conditions based on the 3 above I filled in the filter array. Cheers.